# Laravel Scheduling not firing command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple set up a command for Scheduling that is firing on a cron call

The artisan command works fine yet nothing happens when Scheduling

The Schedule

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('prices:pricing')
            ->everyMinute();
    }
```

The Task

```
protected $signature = 'prices:pricing';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Gets Pricing data and stores in DB';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
     Log::debug('An informational message.');
     }
}
```

The cron

```
* * * * *  www-data  cd /var/www/api  &&  php artisan schedule:run  >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Also I have tried with running

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Comment: so hitting this on command line `* * * * *  www-data  cd /var/www/api  &&  php artisan schedule:run  >> /dev/null 2>&1`
makes the code run right? But this cron is not firing from laravel Schedule?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to `php` in your cron job (e.g., `/usr/local/bin/php`)?

Comment: So the artisan command works fine, but nothing in the cron period

Comment: may be u r facing 500 Error in code. pls check your code by executing it from another way like routes.php once
Check the logs of Laravel Project and Logs of Your Server as well to find the reponse of cron/artisan

Comment: I have done so and it works fine when running from the command line